# Monitor temperature/IO of NVMe drive

Tags: software-rec, io, ssd, temperature

Is there a way to monitor temperature or reads/writes of and NVMe drive (in this case Intel 750). `hdparm`, `udisksctl`, `smartctl`, and `hddtemp` all seem to lack this capability, google searches have been fruitless.

For the curious, this is the only difficulty I've faced running Fedora 23 (Workstation) using NVMe for the system drive.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Using nvme-cli, I can get temperature from a Samsung 950 Pro with this command:

```
nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0 | grep "^temperature"
```

You can get other informations too:

```
nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0

Smart Log for NVME device:nvme0 namespace-id:ffffffff
critical_warning                    : 0
temperature                         : 45 C
available_spare                     : 100%
available_spare_threshold           : 10%
percentage_used                     : 0%
data_units_read                     : 3,020,387
data_units_written                  : 2,330,810
host_read_commands                  : 26,960,077
host_write_commands                 : 15,668,236
controller_busy_time                : 65
power_cycles                        : 98
power_on_hours                      : 281
unsafe_shutdowns                    : 68
media_errors                        : 0
num_err_log_entries                 : 63
Warning Temperature Time            : 0
Critical Composite Temperature Time : 0
```

Note: using kernel 4.6.4

For users access:

/etc/sudoers

```
# For users group
%users ALL = NOPASSWD: nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0 | grep "^temperature"

# For all
ALL ALL = NOPASSWD: nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0 | grep "^temperature"
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! It would be nice if running the cli didn't require superuser privileges though.

Comment: you can add the exact command to /etc/sudoers in order users can access the temperature. [Adding it to the answer]

Comment: Note that hddtemp command is usually restricted to root too.

Comment: The only way to access hddtemp temperature for a user is to access via TCP to the hddtemp daemon (service).
Example: nc localhost 7634 && echo

Comment: That's  what I did--cheers

Answer (score 6):

With [kernel 5.5 and beyond](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-5.5-NVMe-HWMON-Support), temperature information is available to regular users via sysfs. For example, on my system:

```
/sys/class/nvme/nvme0/device/hwmon/hwmon1/name:nvme
/sys/class/nvme/nvme0/device/hwmon/hwmon1/temp1_alarm:0
/sys/class/nvme/nvme0/device/hwmon/hwmon1/temp1_crit:84850
/sys/class/nvme/nvme0/device/hwmon/hwmon1/temp1_input:50850
/sys/class/nvme/nvme0/device/hwmon/hwmon1/temp1_label:Composite
/sys/class/nvme/nvme0/device/hwmon/hwmon1/temp1_max:84850
/sys/class/nvme/nvme0/device/hwmon/hwmon1/temp1_min:-273150
/sys/class/nvme/nvme0/device/hwmon/hwmon1/temp2_input:50850
/sys/class/nvme/nvme0/device/hwmon/hwmon1/temp2_label:Sensor 1
/sys/class/nvme/nvme0/device/hwmon/hwmon1/temp2_max:65261850
/sys/class/nvme/nvme0/device/hwmon/hwmon1/temp2_min:-273150
/sys/class/nvme/nvme0/device/hwmon/hwmon1/temp3_input:62850
/sys/class/nvme/nvme0/device/hwmon/hwmon1/temp3_label:Sensor 2
/sys/class/nvme/nvme0/device/hwmon/hwmon1/temp3_max:65261850
/sys/class/nvme/nvme0/device/hwmon/hwmon1/temp3_min:-273150
```

The different temperatures are in the `*_input` files. The values are T(℃) * 1000. For example, the temperature from sensor 1 is ~51℃.

Comment: Hm, FWIW, on an Alder Lake system with `5.19.12-100.fc35.x86_64` and  WD_BLACK SN850, there is no `/sys/class/nvme/nvme0/device/hwmon` directory. (the temperature does show up in in `nvme smart-log` though). However, there is `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/name -> nvme` with `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/temp1_input` that seems to match the smart-log number.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some steps you can take. Ensure that your Linux kernel version is at least 3.19 and that you have the Intel Linux NVMe drivers installed. If that does not help consider installing the [Linux NVMe command line interface](https://github.com/linux-nvme/nvme-cli).

Comment: Unfortunately the nvme-cli does not appear to have the desired capabilities. And I'm running kernel 4.4.8 (I'm using the NVMe drive for my OS after all).

Comment: I can't think of anything else and Google isn't turning anything up so I guess you either need to do more in-depth research, wait for someone more knowledgeable to answer, or create your own solution. Sorry I couldn't be of greater assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, you may need to find which `hwmon` and `temp` for your system in `/sys/devices/*`

Using `conky`

```
${hwmon 2 temp 1}°C
```

Comment: Could you expand on this answer?